# Why my pin field does not show numbers when typing for the first time?

Tags: flutter

My Code :

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Form(
        child: TextFormField(
          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
          ],
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: TextEditingController(text: formData.pin),
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'PIN 2',
          ),
          onChanged: (newValue) => formData.pin = newValue,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

my problem, The PIN column does not display numbers when first typed, you have to tap again so the numbers can appear, I have attached a gif below:

[image: Screen recording]

I hope The PIN column can display the numbers when first typed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not initialize `TextEditingController` inside the `build` method. This will cause the controller to set its value to the given initial text every time the widget rebuilds.

Move the controller variable to the state, and initialize it in `initState` (you have to use a `StatefulWidget`).

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late TextEditingController pinController; // (1) Define the controller variable

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pinController = TextEditingController(text: formData.pin); // (2) Initialize it
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pinController.dispose(); // (3) Don't forget to dispose after
    super.dispose();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Now use it in the widget like this:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: pinController,
  // ...
)
```

If `formData` is not accessible from the `initState`, chances are you need to refactor the way `formData` is defined. Move it to a place where it's accessible from `initState`.